# Divide a column by another column created from Sub query

Tags: php, laravel

I've this query -

```
$employees = Employee::where('user_id', $user->id)->withCount([
    'answers as questions_received' => function ($query) use($date) {
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', $date);
    }, 
    'answers as correct' => function ($query) use($date) {
        $query->where('correct', 1)->where('created_at', '>=', $date);
    }
]);

$employees = $employees
    ->orderBy('answered', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('correct', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I want to do something like this - `((correct/questions_received) * 100) as percentage`
But don't understand how to do it. :)

Comment: Have you tried using some of the raw query methods? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the table layout, and the `answered` and `correct` columns are of a datatype with values 0 and 1 (such as the `tinyint(1)` datatype Laravel uses for booleans for MySQL).

```
Employees
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+

Answers
+----+-------------+----------+---------+------------+
| id | employee_id | answered | correct | created_at |
+----+-------------+----------+---------+------------+
```

This seems to do the trick:

```
$employees = Employee::select('E.*')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS questions_received')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(correct) AS correct')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(correct) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS percentage')
    ->from('employees AS E')
    ->join('answers AS A', 'E.id', '=', 'A.employee_id')
    ->where('A.created_at', '>=', $date)
    ->where('E.user_id', $user->id)
    ->groupBy('E.id')
    ->get();
```